# img php src asynchronous

Tags: php, image, asynchronous, src

If I use php file as source to image, where:

```
$file = $_GET["file"];
$file_get = get_file_contents("from/".$file);
$fopen = fopen("to/".$file,"w+");
fwrite($fopen, $file_get);
fclose($fopen);
header("Location:to/".$file);
```

And if I use many images of that kind on one page, like:

```
<img src="image.php/?file=img.jpg>
<img src="image.php/?file=img2.jpg>
<img src="image.php/?file=img3.jpg>
...
```

I found that code in image.php doesn't run asynchronously. Images are downloaded one by one. How can I avoid it?

Comment: Sessions can only be opened by one request at a time, all other requests will sit and wait. Close the session as soon as possible to allow other requests to process in parallel.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it also appears you may be bottlenecking on memory usage ... get_file_contents is going to probably be reading the entire image into memory. maybe doing a [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) would be more appropriate

Comment: Btw your having a huge security issue there

Comment: Thank you for help.  @Xatenev, I made it  in security reason)). Only authorized users can see that images. It's a must for my project. Why this is a huge security issue if I make all necessary verifications?

Comment: @Orangepill you are absolutely right. But I need to download file from remote server(cloud).

Comment: @IvanVynnyk since php 4.3 copy works across the network if you have http stream wrappers enabled on your server i.e. `copy("http://remoteserver.com/myimage.jpg", "myimage.jpg");`

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you. How to close it? ))

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Answer (score 0):

I see there some problems in your code. The first is that you have a big security whole when you use the `$_GET` input directly in your code to get an image.

The next one is why do you fetch the content from one file and write them to another file to redirect to them? That is not really fast if you write every time the file to another location.

If you get the content echt echo the content and set the correct header to show the image.

```
header('Content-type:image/png');
readfile($fullpath);
```

Its much easier and you have a less IO to show files. Otherwise you can use a script like PHPThumb which generated smaller versions and cache the files.

http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

Comment: directly $_GET input is just to simplify this example. In real project there are many verifications. Copy or readfile are great, but if I need to fetch file from private cloud through curl get request, where content of file is the respond.